# how to add image icons with navigation menu in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to add image icon with navigation menu in polymer. What should be the ways for that. I want something like following image.

[image: menu with icon]

Comment: I tried with paper-icon-button, iron-image. But cannot get it fixed.

Comment: can you post what you have tried. It should work with either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set of [iron-icons](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons) from Polymer Elements catalogue and choose your favorite icon to work on.

Make sure that you import your component after importing Polymer component

If you want to add custom icons, checkout [iron-iconset](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-iconset) component.

Here is code example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="basic polymer jsbin">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

    <dom-module id="test-app">
      <template>
        
        <style>
          
          :host {
            color: #000;
          }
          
        </style>
        <iron-icon icon="icons:home"></iron-icon>
        <span>Home</span>
        
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          Polymer({
            
            is: 'test-app',
            
            ready: function() {
              
            }
          
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>

  </head>
  <body>
    <test-app></test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```